# c++ typecast base ptr to derived ptr held in a reference class

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I'm trying to create an Object Reference template class that will hold class pointers and everything works except when trying to type cast base class ptr to a derived class ptr.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define null nullptr

class BaseType;
class DerivedType;

template<class T>
class ObjRef {
public:
  T *ptr = null;  //should be private

  ObjRef& operator= (T *ptr) { this->ptr = ptr; return *this; }
  ObjRef& operator= (const ObjRef &ref) { ptr = ref.ptr; return *this; }
  operator T*() const {return ptr;}
  operator T() const {return *ptr;}
  ObjRef() {}
  ObjRef(const ObjRef &copy) { ptr = copy.ptr; }
#ifdef VOID_FIX
  ObjRef(void*p) { ptr = (T*)p; }  //this could fix the bug except would not work with multiple inheritance and is not safe
#else
  ObjRef(T*p) { ptr = p; }
#endif
  ~ObjRef() { }
  T* operator->() const {return ptr;}  //unfortunately operation. (dot) can not be overloaded - that would make life too easy :(
};

class Object {};

class BaseType : public Object {
public:
  int baseValue;
};

class DerivedType : public BaseType {
public:
  operator BaseType*() {return (BaseType*)this;}  //helpful?
  int derivedValue;
};

typedef ObjRef<BaseType> Base;
typedef ObjRef<DerivedType> Derived;

void func4(Base x) {
  x->baseValue = 1;
}

void func5(Derived x) {
  x->derivedValue = 1;
}

int main() {
  Base b = null;
  Derived d = null;
  Base x;

  x = d;  //no type cast needed
  func4((Base)d);  //cast from Derived to Base class - no problem

  b = d;  //base does point to derived
//  func5((Derived)b);  //cast from Base to Derived - does not work (desired syntax)
  // with gcc -fpermissive can be used to change error to warning - can I silence the warning ?
  // what would cl.exe equivalent be?

//  func5((Derived)b.ptr);  //invalid cast, ptr should be private
//  func5((DerivedType*)b);  //invalid cast, ptr should be private
//  func5(dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(b.ptr));  //invalid cast, source type is not polymorphic, ptr should be private

  func5((DerivedType*)b.ptr);  //this works but is undesired and ptr should be private
  func5(static_cast<DerivedType*>(b.ptr));  //works but again is undesired and ptr should be private

  return 0;
}
```

In the example ObjRef<> is a template that holds a pointer to the class defined and is used as a new type.  It works fine except for trying to cast base class to derived class.  Look at how func5() is being called with a base class reference. The first attempt is the desired syntax.  If I use the ptr inside the reference class it will work but that is undesired.

I just feel like I'm missing an operator or something.

Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of misguided things in your code. `#define null nullptr` **No** don't do that. `operator BaseType*() {return (BaseType*)this;}` completely useless; use `static_cast<BaseType*>(&myObject)`. You keep casting with C-style casts; use C++ style casts. Lastly, `ObjRef` seems completely unneeded.

Comment: @Bo - you can if the base class pointer points to a derived class.  Even with multiple inheritance it's possible but ill-advised.

Comment: @Peter - Ok, you tricked me by hiding the `*` for the pointer types and making `Derived` not be derived from `Base`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual I found the solution just moments after posting.
The ObjRef<> class needs to know the base class.
Here is the new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define null nullptr

class BaseType;
class DerivedType;

template<class T>
class ObjRef {
public:
  T *ptr = null;

  ObjRef& operator= (auto *ptr) { this->ptr = ptr; return *this; }
  ObjRef& operator= (const ObjRef<auto> &ref) { ptr = ref.ptr; return *this; }
  operator T*() const {return ptr;}
  ObjRef() {}
  ObjRef(const ObjRef<auto> &copy) { ptr = (T*)copy.ptr; }
  ObjRef(T*p) { ptr = p; }
  ~ObjRef() { }
  T* operator->() const {return ptr;}  //unfortunately operator. (dot) can not be overloaded - that would make life too easy :(
};

class Object {};

class BaseType : public virtual Object {
public:
  int baseValue;
};

class InterfaceType : public virtual Object {
public:
  virtual void func7() {
    printf("it works!\n");
  };
};

typedef ObjRef<InterfaceType> Interface;

class DerivedType : public BaseType, public InterfaceType {
public:
  int derivedValue;
};

typedef ObjRef<BaseType> Base;
typedef ObjRef<DerivedType> Derived;

void func4(Base x) {
  x->baseValue = 1;
}

void func5(Derived x) {
  x->derivedValue = 2;
}

void func6(Interface x) {
  x->func7();
}

int main() {
  Base b = new BaseType();
  Derived d = new DerivedType();
  Base x;

  x = d;  //no type cast needed
  func4((Base)d);  //cast from Derived to Base class - no problem
  printf("BaseValue=%d\n", d->baseValue);

  b = d;  //base does point to derived
  func5((Derived)b);  //cast from Base to Derived - works now!
  printf("DerivedValue=%d\n", d->derivedValue);

  func6(d);

  return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE** : Posted a new version that will work with any level of inheritance but now requires C++14 (auto keyword)

**UPDATE #2** : Now uses a single ObjRef class (still requires C++14).  Unfortunately cl.exe doesn't support 'auto' template parameters yet :(

**UPDATE #3** : Added some test code to prove it works.

Comment: Of course not, there are just null's in there.  Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Ok, updated it with some real test values and works like a charm.  Requires gcc 5.0 (C++14).  Doesn't work with cl.exe yet (come on M$ get with the times!)